# Negative extrusion

Tags: extrude

Where is the setting for negative extrusion in Blender. In case I have the name wrong, this extrudes non-existence, ie you extrude back through an object to make a hole. I can make a pit (hole partway into material), but if I go through the other side it just starts to positive extrude from the back. I can't find the option to remove mesh and make holes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your question is not precise enough. For example you can make holes with booleans, or simply with <kbd>W</kbd> (*Specials*) > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

If you're looking for the same as the *Push-Pull* tool in Sketchup, it was an addon called *Destructive Extrude* in 2.7. It looks like it's not ready for 2.8 yet: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Qlcbbc/

- How it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beZau_wpR-U
- Addon: https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX

As explained in the video, once you've installed the addon, shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: while that addon looks promising, there has to be a way to make holes natively.

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer, maybe give an example of what you want

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode, select the face that you want to make into a hole, and delete it (X).
If you want the hole to have some depth, extrude the face down and then delete it.